# 412 Precondition Failed while PUT request from retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making a put request to the server using retrofit2. With same token, body and path using postman, the content is successfully edited but the same thing comes with error using retrofit2 stating Precondition failed. 412 error.

```
@PUT("issues/{id}/")
Call<IssueList> putIssue(@Header("Authorization")String token,
                         @Body IssueList issue,
                         @Path("id") Double issueId);
```

Edit

```
Call<IssueList> issuePostRequest = postService.putIssue(Splash.token,
                    issueRequest,editIssueId);
            issuePostRequest.enqueue(new Callback<IssueList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<IssueList> call, Response<IssueList> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                        System.out.println(response.message());
                        System.out.println(response.code());
                        System.out.println(response.headers());
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("passed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<IssueList> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Response is not successful.

Comment: try without the last slash, @PUT("issues/{id}")

Comment: I've tried that before. That is not working.

Comment: Are you sure the id is a ``Double``? Sounds a bit weird. I don't even know how retrofit would format this, but I'd suspect it adds decimal places which sounds odd for an id. This would result in a url like ``issues/123.0/``

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone, I found what the problem was. It was not the retrofit but with object I was sending. I was sending an object through @Body which had unwanted variable.

I learnt about http interceptor log, which is a great tool of retrofit and I was able to locate the root error.